# How transaction manipulation handles in Blockchain?

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I'm new to Blockchain and would like to understand few concepts in a detail. 
After reading about basics of Blockchain, one thing is unclear to me about tx. manipulation.

For instance, A has some (i.e: $10) money and A is sending half($5) of it to B. but C manipulate that transaction before going to Blockchain and set $10 instead.

Now, A wanted to send only $5, but some how A's account will get empty since miner will check A has enough balance or not.

How Blokchain resolves this type of scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transactions are signed by their original sender. Someone could copy a transaction and change it then resend it to the rest of the network but the rest of the network would ignore it because the signature would be invalid.